# Как запустить Flask (python) сайт на PythonEveryWhere?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, веб-сервер, хостинг

Как запустить Flask (python) сайт на Python Everywhere?
Всё делал по этой документации https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/Flask/
И все вроде бы заработало, но когда я кликнул по ссылке, сайт был не доступен... Посоветуйте другие документации (желательно на русском, но не обязательно) или возможно кто то уже сталкивался с такой проблемой и знает как она решается. Кстати я запускал сайт без домена, возможно в этом проблемма

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую воспользоваться официальной документацией PythonAnyWhere: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/

или поискать ответ на их личном форуме:

https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/

**А так же такой вопрос был уже задан на Иностранном Stack-e:**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51498728/pythonanywhere-com-flask-web-app-no-module-named-flask-app